# matlab timer functions

Tags: matlab

I want to call function A in a program. This function has a for loop inside and I'd like to shorten amount of iterations but not just changing the upper limit. How could I do it in this case? I was thinking if Matlab is capable of doing something like: one timer inside a function (or maybe inside a loop) and second in the main program that calls this function? But only rough idea, I'm a beginner. Please feed back if this is good idea and how could it be implemented?

thank you!

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you're trying to do this? Perhaps with some simplified example code? Why is it not enough to change the limits of the loop?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to kill the for loop if too much time has elapsed since it started running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about having a maximum elapsed time condition in your loop, something along the lines of,

```MATLAB
MAX_T = 10;
tic; 
for n=1:NMAX
  % Call your loop functions 
  .  
  . 
  % Break if youve spent too much time in the loop 
  if toc > MAX_T; break; end;
end
```

There are also ways of optimizing this, such as only checking the value of toc every N iterations.